# ASP File Object Issue

Tags: asp-classic, filesystemobject

I am working on an ASP classic website, which the client reported suddenly exhibited an issue with a previously working function which listed only "image" file types.  Upon reading the code, I found that the loop that lists the files in a folder, uses the InStr() function to identify files by their type, which should be "image."  However, I found that something must have changed in the OS, as the type is not longer "image", but "JPG", or "PNG", etc.  This dramatically changes the way the code works.  Following is a snipped of the code:

```
Set oFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(Server.MapPath(sCurrentDirectoryPath))
Set oSubFolder = oFolder.Files
                            
    iFileCount = 0
                            
    For Each oFileName in oSubFolder
                
        If InStr(1, LCase(oFileName.Type),"image") > 0 Then
            iFileCount = iFileCount + 1
        End If
    Next
```

Because the InStr() function is trying to find a file type of "image", no files are counted up, and the function returns zero files found.  Whilst debugging, I found that the value being returned by oFileName.Type, was as follows:

This is the file type:JPG File
This is the file type:JPG File
This is the file type:Text Document
This is the file type:Data Base File

Files in the folder were two "whatever.jpg" files, a "whatever.txt" file, and a "thumbs.db" file.  So, it appears that the OS (Windows Server 2019) may have changed to be less generic with reporting an "image" file, and is now reporting "JPG file" or "PNG file", etc.  This of course, breaks this code!  Are there any suggestions from you'all on how I could go about modifying this code to work on reporting exactly how many image files are present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows 10, the `Type` values for `.jpg` and `.png` files are `JPEG image` and `PNG image` respectively. What OS are you using?

Also, `Type` doesn't actually analyze the file, you could have a `virus.exe` file in the folder that has been renamed to `virus.jpg`, and the `Type` value will still show it as `JPEG`. So if the function is indented to check user uploaded content to ensure images are actually images, the `Type` value will be of no use. If you have root access you could install a COM DLL that uses a program such as ExifTool to properly analyze files (https://github.com/as08/ClassicASP.ExifTool), however that would be a complete rewrite.

But assuming you're not looking to check if an image file is actually an image file, you could just split the filename extensions and use `Select Case` to count the image files if your OS is returning just `XXX file` and no longer `XXX image` in the `Type` value (alternatively you could split the `Type` value, but you'd still need to check for valid image file extensions):

```vb
Dim oFSO, oFolder, oSubFolder, oFileName, iFileCount, oFileNameSplit

Set oFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(Server.MapPath(sCurrentDirectoryPath))
Set oSubFolder = oFolder.Files
                        
    iFileCount = 0
                        
    For Each oFileName In oSubFolder
    
        oFileNameSplit = Split(oFileName.Name,".")
        
        If uBound(oFileNameSplit) > 0 Then
        
            Select Case Trim(lCase(oFileNameSplit(uBound(oFileNameSplit))))
            
                Case "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif" ' Maybe add some more extensions...
                
                iFileCount = iFileCount + 1
                
            End Select
        
        End If
    
    Next

Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing
Set oSubFolder = Nothing

Response.Write(iFileCount)
```

Comment: Hello Adam.  Thank you for your answer!  I should have mentioned the OS, and have edited the question to include that it is Windows Server 2019, which is functionally the same as Windows 10.  I believe your solution will work, so long as the client is aware and restricted to using the most popular image formats/file types.  I believe there is also a way to use a component like that offered by Chilkat, to inspect the first 2 bytes of a file to determine it's type, but yes, that would be a complete re-write  I'll look into this and consult with the client to find which way to go.

Comment: I finally got around to implementing this, and it appears to be working so far, but it is still of interest that this suddenly stopped working the way it was.  This is code what was written more than 10-years ago that was working, until some kind of Microsoft update caused the File System Object to work in a different manner.  I will try taking this up with Microsoft next, then comment more when I have more information.

Comment: When I up-voted it, I thought that was accepting it.  Is there something else I need to do?  Please let me know.  Thank you!  Never mind, figured it out.  Thank you for your help!  I suppose it would be a different question (for Microsoft perhaps) as to why the behavior of the FileSystem object suddenly changed after so many years of use.